# RDS(dynamic schema) -> AWS opensearch by using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue, opensearch

I am using AWS RDS(MySQL) and I would like to sync this data to AWS elasticsearch in real-time.

I am thinking that the best solution for this is AWS Glue but I am not sure about I could realize what I want.

This is information for my RDS database:
■ RDS
・I would like to sync several tables(MySQL) to opensearch(1 table to 1 index).
・The schema of tables will be changed dynamically.
・The new column will be added or The existing columns will be removed since previous sync.
(so I also have to sync this schema change)

Could you teach me roughly whether I could do these things by AWS Glue?

I wonder if AWS Glue can deal with dynamic schame change and syncing in (near) real-time.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Glue Now have OpenSearch connector but Glue is like a ETL tool and does batch kind of operation very well  but event based or very frequent load to elastic search might not be best fit ,and cost also can be high .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-elastisearch-connector.html

DMS can help not completely   as you have mentioned schema keeps changing .

**Logstash Solution**

Since Elasticsearch 1.5, Elasticsearch added jdbc input plugin in Logstash to sync MySQL data into Elasticsearch.

**AWS Native solution**

You can have a lambda function on MySQL event  [Invoking a Lambda function from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)

The lambda will write to Kinesis Firehouse in json and kinesis can load into OpenSearch .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can AWS Glue deal with the schema change of data source? I read the guide and it said that a crawler detects schema. Could it be changeable?

Comment: You it can do that .Yo need to create a crawler that will crawl to your data base and if any changes it will detect .You can also schedule Crawler so that time to time it will keep checking the changes

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been reading a AWS Glue tutorial but still difficult for me...   if I `can schedule Crawler`, how often would it be? 1 minutes in the shortest interval (by EventBridge)? I would like to sync as soon as the data is registered, thank you.

Comment: Yes ,1  minutes is shortest interval. Please also remember it will cost you a much if you run your crawler very frequent and also crawler takes few minutes to finish depends on data in that having crawler schedule very frequent will not be helpful .

Comment: thank you! I got the picture of AWS Glue with clawer. Can I use Glue without clawer? Does it make sync faster?

Comment: Yes You can use but in that case you need to identify changes by yourself and then do operation .Glue is basically for Batch kind operation but Your use case is event based .Looks to me Glue will not fit your use case .You can also use Crawler without glue job/task